# external php inclusion for table generation

Tags: php, html, dom, web-applications

I have been self-teaching PHP while working on a project so my code may not be the most elegant, I'm still learning. I'd really like to clean up my code a little and make sensible functions to replace my copious amounts of spaghetti code. I've gotten test functions to work fine, but now that I want to generate my tables with a function I'm having problems and generating no errors, which is making it troublesome to debug. I have three files "functions.php", "tblDesc.php", and "index.php" as shown below

index.php:

```
<html>
<?php
require 'header.php'
?>
 <head>
    <title>
      Asset Manager
     </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 include_once('navBar.php');
 ?>
<?php
include_once('tblDesc.php');
?>
    </body>
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
function initTable($query, $tblID){
    // Begin Table generation

    print "<table id='".$tblID."'> ";
    $result = $dbAssetManTest->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print "<thead>";
    print " <tr> ";
    // pulls field data for table generation
    foreach ($row as $field => $value){
        print " <th>$field</th> ";
    }
    print " </tr> ";
    print "</thead>";
    // end foreach
    //body of Table
    print "<tbody>";
    // pulls live data from DB
    $data = $dbAssetManTest->query($query);
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($data as $row){
        print " <tr> ";
        foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
            print " <td>$value</td> ";
        } // end field loop
        print " </tr> ";
    } // end record loop
    print "</tbody>";
    print "</table>";
}
?>
```

tblDesc.php

```
<?php
require "functions.php";

// Begin Table generation
$queryBR="select foo from bar;";
$tblIDBR='tblFooBar';

initTable($queryBR, $tblIDBR);
?>
```

If I take the contents of the function `initTable` and replace the line `initTable($queryBR, $tblIDBR);` with the contents from functions.php everything works, but; when I try and separate the function passing it the vaulues query and tableID my page halts loading at `<table id='tblBROnHand'>`.

As such THIS works but looks terrible:

```
<?php
// Begin Table generation
$queryBR="select foo from bar;";
$tblID='tblFooBar';
// Begin Table generation
print "<table id='".$tblID."'> ";
$result = $dbAssetManTest->query($queryBR);
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print "<thead>";
print " <tr> ";
// pulls field data for table generation
foreach ($row as $field => $value){
    print " <th>$field</th> ";
}
print " </tr> ";
print "</thead>";
// end foreach
//body of Table
print "<tbody>";
// pulls live data from DB
$data = $dbAssetManTest->query($queryBR);
$data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($data as $row){
    print " <tr> ";
    foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
        print " <td>$value</td> ";
    } // end field loop
    print " </tr> ";
} // end record loop
print "</tbody>";
print "</table>";
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated!

Comment: Put ini_set('display_errors',1); at the beginning of the file, or look in the PHP/Apache error log

Comment: Run your code without the custom functions. If it works, you'll see that something needs to be added. It's a variable scope.

Comment: I think you will find this is a SCOPE issue, it normally is when you move code into functions

Comment: `$dbAssetManTest` will not be visible in a function unless you pass it in as a parameter

Comment: Come to that I dont see `$dbAssetManTest` defined in the code you say works either

Comment: $dbAssetManTest is a PDO object defined in my PDO config file which is included in my header.php (where ive dumped most of my includes for JS and CSS)

Comment: Then add another param for that to the function and pass it into the function on the call. **Dont use global if anyone should suggest that**

Comment: Little note: I dont see an include of `header.php` in the code that you say works either

Comment: the header include is in the index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have now made a function of that code you have changed the scope of the variables used inside it.

In other words the variables in the main line code are no longer visible to code within the function, namely the `$dbAssetManTest` variable

So pass that variable as a parameter to the function and it will then be visible and usable inside the function

```
<?php
function initTable($dbAssetManTest, $query, $tblID){
    // Begin Table generation

    print "<table id='".$tblID."'> ";
    $result = $dbAssetManTest->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print "<thead>";
    print " <tr> ";
    // pulls field data for table generation
    foreach ($row as $field => $value){
        print " <th>$field</th> ";
    }
    print " </tr> ";
    print "</thead>";
    // end foreach
    //body of Table
    print "<tbody>";
    // pulls live data from DB
    $data = $dbAssetManTest->query($query);
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($data as $row){
        print " <tr> ";
        foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
            print " <td>$value</td> ";
        } // end field loop
        print " </tr> ";
    } // end record loop
    print "</tbody>";
    print "</table>";
}
?>
```

And when you call it add the parameter to the function all

```
<?php
require "functions.php";

// Begin Table generation
$queryBR="select foo from bar;";
$tblIDBR='tblFooBar';

initTable($dbAssetManTest, $queryBR, $tblIDBR);
?>
```

It is also a better idea not to output directly from a function or method, instead build a string of what you want output and return it from the function. This way it is possible to effect the output after the call is made. Not easy in this case, but as a general rule at least it may be possible

So

```
<?php
function initTable($dbAssetManTest, $query, $tblID){
    // Begin Table generation

    $htm = "<table id='".$tblID."'> ";
    $result = $dbAssetManTest->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $htm .= "<thead>";
    $htm ,=  " <tr> ";
    // pulls field data for table generation
    foreach ($row as $field => $value){
        $htm .= " <th>$field</th> ";
    }
    $htm .= " </tr> ";
    $htm .= "</thead>";
    // end foreach
    //body of Table
    $htm .= "<tbody>";
    // pulls live data from DB
    $data = $dbAssetManTest->query($query);
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($data as $row){
        $htm .= " <tr> ";
        foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
            $htm .= " <td>$value</td> ";
        } // end field loop
        $htm .= " </tr> ";
    } // end record loop
    $htm .= "</tbody>";
    $htm .= "</table>";

    return $htm;
}
?>
```

And when you call it add the parameter to the function all

```
<?php
require "functions.php";

// Begin Table generation
$queryBR="select foo from bar;";
$tblIDBR='tblFooBar';

$htm = initTable($dbAssetManTest, $queryBR, $tblIDBR);
echo $htm;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code as first line of your function,

```
global $dbAssetManTest;
```

Comment: `global` yuk yuk cough cough... puke

Comment: @RiggsFolly, can you please let me know the issue in  using global for db connection. I did this in a project recently & it worked. That's why I suggested here. Sorry if am mis-directing OP with my answer

Comment: It works its just a horrible idea. instead pass the connection as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Yes, from your comment I understood that it could be an horrible idea. But can you please let me know the issue

Comment: The problem with using global is that anywhere in your code if you alter a global it effects anything that uses it. And often this is done by mistake with far reaching consequences

Comment: @RiggsFolly you rock! if you make your comment an answer about adding another param and passing the PDO object in the param I'll set it to the correct answer, that solved my problem!

Comment: Got it, thanks @RiggsFolly. I will consider this in my projects